# How can I prevent the menu bar delay?

Tags: gtk, gtkbuilder

In every GTK 3 application I have seen there is a delay of about one second before the menu bar appears when an application is launched. I also have this problem with the application I'm currently working on. Is there a way to prevent this delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is (was) apparently a bug in GTK 3 previous to version 3.4 as it does not show up in the last version.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the technique described [here](http://jderose.blogspot.com/2011/09/our-apps-should-all-launch-instantly.html).  Basically you delay the bulk of your window setup, doing it in an idle-time function. This is mostly smoke and mirrors though, as your application just *appears* to be ready sooner.

Other than that, if you strace (under linux at least), most of the start up time seems to be I/O performed by libraries and out of our control as application programmers.  I have a feeling that some of it could be done on demand (lazily) but I don't know if anyone is working on that or if it is even feasable.

Comment: As I see it my problem is more like the opposite - the window is displayed before the menu is ready.

Comment: On what system(s)/app(s) are you seeing this?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 11.10 with the Blackbox window manager but the delay also occurs in Gnome. Gedit 3.2.3 and Image viewer 3.2.1 are examples of applications which exhibit this problem.